# laravel localization in js file

Tags: php, laravel, localization

this is my lang messages

```
'Next' => 'Keyingisi',
```

this is my code which is I used in blade.php , it is worked

```
{{__('main_trans.Next')}}
```

but I want to write this code inside js file like this

```
sNext: "<?php __('main_trans.Next') ?>",
```

But it is not working , can you give me advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't; `<?php ?>` and `{{ }}` cannot be used in a `.js` file. If this is a `<script>` within a `.blade.php` file, then you can.

Or, you can assign it as a variable *before* importing the JS file, like so:

`file.blade.php`:

```
<script>var translation = "{{ __('main_trans.Next') }}";</script>
<script src="{{ asset('path/to/file.js') }}"/>
```

Then, in your `.js` file, you access it via the JS variable `sNext: translation`

Comment: I'm not clear with your solution...could you explain how to assign the variable before importing the js file

Comment: Hi, about the previous comment, i read this https://thewebtier.com/implementing-laravel-localization-in-javascript and now it became clear... you can access the variable using window.translation

Comment: This is a bit of an older answer, and in modern JS, this would be `const translation = "{{ __('main_trans.Next') }}";`, but that _is_ assignment. In `file.js`, `translation` would be available as a variable, or, as you stated, `window.translation`, and you'd be able to do `{ sNext: translation }` (in the context of the question being asked)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
sNext: "{{ __('main_trans.Next') }}"
```

OR

```
sNext: "@lang('main_trans.Next')"
```